# Responsive Page - forcing responsive layout

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap, but the question is relevant to any responsive framework

I have a responsive page that looks (in a simplistic way) like this

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="row page">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
       some stuff
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
       some other stuff
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to use this layout but to have the scope of the responsiveness be on some parent div (`.wrap` in this case) and not on the window, meaning if the parent div is at same specific sizes, force the responsive breakpoints to be in effect.

So this way, I can place this 'template' anywhere in the page and the results will be different according the wrap size and not on the screen/window size

Is there a way to do this? Or am I in outer space?

Comment: So fixed size for `.wrap` and fluid sizes for its children... what's the problem?

Comment: that means I can't use the framework and need to recreate parts of it

Comment: I see, since you said "but the question is relevant to any responsive framework" I thought you were going to butcher it anyway (which I think you should, actually, because it probably won't give you such functionality out of the box).

Comment: ok so you think the best thing to do here is to set some wrap class and have a bunch of classes with fluid sizes as the grid col replacement?

Comment: That's one option. But I don't know what you're trying to achieve, like are you planning to use media queries, JS modifications, etc.

Comment: like everything, I'm trying to do it with least amount of effort. Thought there is some magic js voodoo to make a parent behave responsively

Answer (score 0):

I think there is now way to check for the containers div width (using CSS), but yes you can try checking for the browser size and add/remove some class width which can give similar results.

```
@media (max-width: 768px){ 
      .wrap{ 
        width:1170px 
      } 
    }
@media (min-width: 767px){ 
          .wrap{ 
            width:767px 
          } 
        }
```

Or even better, you can use jQuery. `var $widthOfWrap = $('.wrap').width()`